# Button does not work using function component in react

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and I've been told its a better way to use function components than class components and I have come to an error where I am unable to show components that I included, I don't really understand what is wrong hence the explanation might be wrong.

Please see my sandbox link for errors

https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-andras-y1g6o?file=/src/App.js

My code as below

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "antd";

const Order = () => {
  const showAction = () => {
    <Button type="primary" size="small">
      {" "}
      {"View"}
    </Button>;
    <h1>Here</h1>;
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello{showAction()} Button is here</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Order;
```

I am expecting it to show Hello {Button} Here Button is here, but instead it shows

Hello Button is here

Comment: You could be missing `return` inside your `showAction function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the working code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "antd";

const Order = () => {
  const showAction = () => (
    <div>
      <Button type="primary" size="small">
        {" "}
        {"View"}
      </Button>
      <h1>Here</h1>
    </div>
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello{showAction()} Button is here</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Order;
```

And here's what was wrong with your code:

1. `showAction` function wasn't returning anything (because you used braces instead of parentheses).
2. All jsx elements must have a single parent element. Notice that I have added a `<div>` that wraps the button and the heading component. You could have also used `<span>` or any other component/tag of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

@Jalaj has already broken down the problem very nicely, so the only thing I would like to add is that in the case of your `showAction` element, you can skip adding parentheses or curly braces altogether. When doing so, JS assumes a return statement. This will work like a charm:

```
const showAction = () => 
    <Fragment>
      <Button type="primary" size="small">
        {" "}
        {"View"}
      </Button>
      <h1>Here</h1>
    </Fragment>
```